# Как решить проблему с изменением значения Margin WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь задать отступы элемента управления от окна, но возникла проблема при изменении одного из значений меняются и другие значения margin, как сделать, чтобы другие значения не менялись при измененении одного и существует ли возможность установить значение Auto для Margin. Как быть, если на форме есть много текстовых полей, например, и других элементов управления и им всем приходится задавать Margin вручную, возможно ли автоматическое задание Margin для всех элементов управления находящихся, например, в StackPanel?

```
Button button1 = new Button();
button1.Margin = new Thickness(-700, 500, 140, 0);
```

Comment: В WPF вообще-то говоря не рекомендуется производить layout при помощи `Margin`'ов, для этого есть намного более адекватные средства.

Answer (score 1):

Задания свойства всем элементам делается через стили (если оно одинаково).
Создаешь стиль в ресурсах панели без ключа и он автоматически применяется всем дочерним элементам.

Auto для margin не имеет смысла, такое поведение нужно реализовывватьчерез alignment.

Можно написать конвертер и забиндить их друг на друга или на какой-то внешний источник.

Comment: Да даже если через стили, все равно все будет сдвигаться. Основная проблема которая щас возникает вообщем есть одна форма. На ней есть 16 ChekBoxов при нажатии на кнопку форма должна измениться не открыться новая, а в зависимости от того сколько CheckBoxoв я выбрал столько текстовых полей должно создасться в StackPanelи, сейчас все текстовые поля и кнопки сдвигаются при выборе checkboxoв на этой же форме выбрал 2 показать 2, выбрал 10 показать 10 все остальные скрыть.

Comment: Плюс на форме нужно разместить ещё и другие элементы управления TreeView слева, текстовые поля по середине, Panel справа, после каждого текстового поля listbox рядом скажым текстовым полем две кнопки, и кнопки внизу после всех текстовых полей. И нужно им всем задать разный Margin. Т.е. все это должна автоматически генерироваться. И как это быстро сделать?

Answer (score -1):

В XAML разметке (если не надо создавать это всё динамически) устанавливаешь свойство margin, можно даже это свойство связать ...Binding...и тут значение с которым хочешь связать, и оно будет динамически меняться в режиме реального времент при изменении того значения от которого зависит